# After installing an SSD, my laptop freezes when I start it up

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, bios

After I installed a new formatted SSD my HP 250 G2 notebook freezes.

When I start it up I get a blank screen and when I push an `F` key after starting, I only get message in corner and nothing happens. Also tried to update bios but no response. Tried to get in bios settings also that gives only the message in corner `bios setup options`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or even on what happened. E.g. what do you mean with 'freezes'? Does it POST? Does it start windows and then hang? Why the heck would you try to update the BIOS (assuming you have an older computer with BIOS int he firmware and not a recent one with EFI firmware). etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

Not a great question but I would start by putting your old drive in (if it is available) and see if that still works. If it does then there is something wrong with the SSD drive. If it doesn't and you have the same issue then you have damaged something when swapping out the drive.

Comment: It does not even sound like it is even attempting to POST, I am not sure, what a new system drive would do.

Comment: thanks for the replys   when I turn my laptop on it doesn't post I only get a blanc screen when I push f10 after restart you should go to bios settings only thing I get is a message in the corner with text ,,f10 bios setup option ,, but it does not go to the bios screen